# How to paste a hypertext in a google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to paste a hypertext in google spreadsheet, but it gets converted to plain text and the link is lost. It does paste properly with the linking in google docs but not in google spreadsheets :(

Answer (score 1):

When you paste, make sure not to double click on the cell in the cell that you want to paste, otherwise the cell it will go into edit mode.

**Solution**: If you single click the cell and paste the hyperlink, the hyperlink should be preserved.